# Counting ternary strings of length $6$ with exactly two $0$'s, at least one $0$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

*A*. How many ternary strings of length $6$ contain exactly two $0$s.
 *B*. How many ternary strings of length $6$ contain at least one 0.

For *A* I think it's $\frac{6!}{(6-2)!}*2^4$ because the first part would be choosing $2$ $0$s and the second part filling the rest of the $4$ slots with either only $1$s or $2$s and then for part *B* I got $\binom{6}{1}\frac{6!}{(6-1)!1!}$ because choosing $1$ zero would give you at least one zero?

Comment: For $A$, there should be $\binom 62$ ways to choose the two slots.  For $B$ it is easier to count those with no $0's$.

Comment: As a suggestion;   whatever ideas you have for counting things, try them on smaller collections.  Here, for instance, take length $2$ or length $3$.  Easy to enumerate the answers there directly and you can check it against your methods.

Comment: "*...because the first part would be chosing[sic] 2 0s...*" To clarify, $\binom{6}{2}=\dfrac{6!}{(6-2)!\color{red}{2!}}$, you forgot something

Comment: Yeah i knew that for part A I just forgot to write the second 2! So it would be (6!/((6-2)!*2!))×2^4 then right?

Answer (score 2):

For A you choose the positions for the zeroes in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways and then for each of the remaining 4 spots we have 2 choices (either one or two). Hence the number of ways is $\binom{6}{2}\times 2^4$.

For B it is easiest to consider the set of length 6 ternary strings without a zero (this is the complement). There are $2^6$ such strings (each position is either a one or a two). There are $3^6$ ternary strings strings of length 6 (we have three choices for each position). Hence there are $3^6-2^6$ ternary strings of length $6$ with at least one zero.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin with the second part:
How many ternary strings of length $6$ contain at least one $0$.

The only alternative to "at least one $0$" is that the string contains no $0$.  The number of strings (of length six) with no $0$, if the strings are ternary, is $2^6$.  So I think that you should be subtracting $2^6$ from $3^6$.  Using combinations as you did doesn't make sense to me since you are counting numbers of subsets of a given size, but ternary strings aren't easily represented as subsets.  On the other hand, it is easy and natural to map back and forth between a binary string and a subset.

Comment: Well, I could easily reformulate the objection that I don't see a connection between ternary strings and subsets as a question about what is the connection between counting ternary strings and counting subsets.  "Doesn't make sense to me" isn't the same as "doesn't make sense."

Comment: I wrote "Using combinations as you did" in reference to the "choose" function that provides the "number of combinations", in contrast with permutations, etc.  I don't see why it's a problem that I made reference to putting three to a some power, since it has an obvious, direct connection with counting ternary strings.  The problem I saw was specifically applying the "choose function."  I had no objection to the mere fact that some kind of combinatorial argument was provided.

Comment: "a problem can have more than one way to arrive at the solution" -- I agree 100% with that comment in general, but I don't think that what we're seeing in this thread is that subtle.

Comment: "and then for part B I got 6 choose 1" is still visible in the original asked by the OP.  It's not clear to me where you're getting information about "the last edit made by OP."  If you could provide a link to something specific regarding the standards of stack.exchange relevant to the content of these comments, I will take a look.  Are the standards imposed on people who are posting answers higher than the standards imposed on people who are posting questions?  I have noticed that a lot of questions appear to have zero answers until after I click and read "comments" that are answers.